# Discord.py Music Bot- Song Download Speed

Tags: python, discord.py, audio-player

So, I have successfully setup my discord music bot, but have a slight kind of annoying issue.
Whenever I do .play (song url), my bot downloads the song into a folder and then plays the song through the bot into discord. Everything works great, except for how slow the song actually downloads. I was wondering if there is any way to boost the download speed to make the music bot more efficient? I have 600+mb download and 20+mb upload, but the music files tend to download in KBs.

[image]